# How to convert Json into C# object?

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions, data-conversion, azure-durable-functions

I have a specific Json that I want to convert to C# class object:

Json:

```
{
    "Database": "DEMO",
    "Schema": "PUBLIC",
    "Warehouse": "TEST_WH",
    "Query": "Call proc();",
    "Role": "SYSADMIN",
    "IsOpsTestRequest": "false",
    "QueryParameters": {
        "Param1": "abc",
        "Param2": "def"
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class Request_Body
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string IsOpsTestRequest { get; set; }
    public List<(string, string)> QueryParameters { get; set; }
}
```

I am sending this json while making a post request to my azure functions http function (durable functions) and then I am trying to convert this json to C# object.

If I remove `QueryParameter` List variable from class and also remove `QueryParameter` from json than it runs perfect but I want this `QueryParameter` in json and it should be generic - it can contain further attributes like `param1` and `param2` or sometimes maybe more. So it should be generic.

In my http trigger function I am converting json to class object as follow:

```
Request_Body data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<Request_Body>();
```

How can I deserialize the json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON for `QueryParameters` does not represent a list or array.  A list or array in JSON would have square brackets (`[...]`) surrounding the values.

However, the JSON can be represented by `Dictionary<string, string>`. So your class should look like this:

```
public class Request_Body
{
    public string Database { get; set; }
    public string Schema { get; set; }
    public string Warehouse { get; set; }
    public string Query { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string IsOpsTestRequest { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> QueryParameters { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try newtonsoft json package from nuget and use serialize and deserialize methods. For example:

```
public class Account { 
     public string Email { get; set; }
     public bool Active { get; set; } 
     public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } 
     public IList<string> Roles { get; set; } }

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json); 

Console.WriteLine(account.Email);
```

[You can check here for more about this package](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm)